# merge objects inside array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

My Code here return the response like this

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "0": {
            "first_name": [
                "The first name field is required."
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "last_name": [
                "The last name field is required."
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            "mobile": [
                "The mobile must be an integer.",
                "The mobile must be at least 9."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to combine objects  and remove numbers to return like this

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {

            "first_name": [
                "The first name field is required."
            ],

            "last_name": [
                "The last name field is required."
            ],

            "mobile": [
                "The mobile must be an integer.",
                "The mobile must be at least 9."
            ]

    }
}

private function transformErrors(ValidationException $exception)
{
    $errors = [];

    foreach ($exception->errors() as $field => $message) {
         $errors[]  =  [
              $field  => $message
          ];

    }
    return  (object)$errors;
}
```

what is best way to handle response in this way

Comment: Is this php code gives `code`, `message` and `errors` or just `errors` ?

Comment: convert your array to collection and the then use flatten method.
`$finalized_errors = collect($errors); return $finalized_errors->flatten():`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values()` function to gather the values from your errors array. Something like this:

```
$yourArray['errors'] = array_values($yourArray['errors']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just want to transform multidimensionnal array into a simple array.

You can try to use :

```
private function transformErrors(ValidationException $exception)
{
    return array_values($exception->errors());
}
```